# ¿Como instalar la versión actual de laravel?¿O determinada versión en mi computadora?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Miren cuando instale Laravel(hoy 04 de Febrero de 2020), leyendo la documentación oficial desde su página:
[Instalación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation#installing-laravel)

Es decir, ejecutando el siguiente script:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Asumí que se me iba a instalar la última versión o la versión estable, pero se me instaló la versión 3.0.1. 
¿Entonces como hago para instalar la versión actual en mi computadora? No en un proyecto determinado.

Tengo entendido que si quiero crear un proyecto con determinada versión puedo ejecutar alguno de los dos siguientes scripts:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel appName "5.1.*"
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.1.*" appName
```

O bien si quiero crear un proyecto con la versión que tengo instalada en mi compu, lo cual es mucho más simplificado:

```
laravel new blog
```

Es decir, quisiera utilizar este último script y no los otros dos de más arriba.

Comment: `laravel new blog` te crea un proyecto en que versión?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ me lo crea en la version 3.0.1, supongo que es por el instalador que descargue a través de Composer. Sino, no se

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás instalando es el **Instalador de Laravel**, no Laravel como tal. En efecto, al día de hoy (04 de Febrero de 2020 -no de 2019-) esa es la última versión de dicho instalador.

Si sigues la documentación, recibirás la última versión de Laravel, no lo dudes, a menos que tengas algún caché antiguo de los repositorios en tu máquina (no creo que sea tu caso).

---

Para instalar la última versión de Laravel (sin su instalador), basta con ejecutar esta línea, asumiendo que uses Linux:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mi-proyecto --prefer-dist
```

---

Para instalar una versión específica, varía un poco esta línea:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mi-proyecto 5.5.*
```

Comment: Jajaja perdon por la equivocación del año. Uso Windows10, aunque uso la terminal Cygwin. Asi que, como seria siendo Windows? o con los scripts que escribiste en la terminal Cygwin anda?

Comment: Hace como 10 años no uso Windows.